# how to redirect page using click in <a> tag in angular

Tags: asp.net, angular, redirect, asp.net-web-api, tags

My Existing code

```
<a class="getStart-button line blue" href="#" (click)="navigateBack()" title="Back">Back</a>
```

I want to use code without href like this:

```
 <a class="getStart-button line blue" (click)="navigateBack()" title="Back">Back</a>
```

Comment: That's perfectly valid, what's in  `navigateBack` ?

Comment: navigateBack() {
        this.BackToList.emit("List");
    }

Comment: you can use ```location.reload();``` instead of ```navigateBack()```.

Comment: Simply Use `<a routerLink="../">Go Back</a>`

Answer (score 1):

Okay, try this.

```
<a class="getStart-button line blue" (click)="navigateBack()" title="Back">Back</a>
```

In component.ts:

```
   import { Location, LocationStrategy, PathLocationStrategy } from '@angular/common';

@Component({
  selector: 'selector',
  providers: [Location, { provide: LocationStrategy, useClass: PathLocationStrategy }],
  template: `your tempalte`
})

export class Component {
  constructor(private location: Location) { }

  public navigateBack(): void {
    this.location.back();
  }
}
```

Read more about [Angular location service here](https://angular.io/api/common/Location).